# What is the right path to be followed on Chess.com for learning Chess?

Tags: learning, online-chess, training, beginner

I am a beginner in Chess. I know the basics but I have very very little practice as of now and I've shortlisted Chess.com to learn and improve my game.

I am yet to buy a premium subscription there but before that I want to test the website with (as much as possible) content available in the basic (free) version. But, there are so many sections in the 'Learn' area only like Puzzles, Lessons, Videos, Openings, Drills and then so many lessons inside each of them.

I'm getting a little confused as to where to start. The reason I'm asking for a right path is because I don't want to mistakenly throw away the option of learning from Chess.com just because I started with things that were probably too advanced for me to start with.

Also, if anyone has any other suggestion besides Chess.com for online platforms for a beginner to learn Chess, then that's also most welcome.

Comment: Get your hands on a tactics book and some basic strategy guide like Nimzovich's "My System"

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [The path of learning chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/the-path-of-learning-chess?rq=1) and see how you can match this with what chess.com offers.

Starting with tactics, a couple of basic general chess principles and playing slower time controls is probably a good start. Avoid learning openings by heart. Watch videos aimed at beginners on youtube, chess24 or any other website (there are questions on SE about recommended websites as well).

IMO there is so much free material for beginners out there that I'd rather invest the money in a good book or for joining a chess club than paying for some website.

Once you are beyond the beginner stage you will want to figure out your main weaknesses and work more on those. Having a stronger player look over your game is very useful in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend these collections of [mate-in-1](https://szachydzieciom.pl/?page_id=63160) and [mate-in-2](https://szachydzieciom.pl/?page_id=63164) puzzles. They are powered by a unique software system not available anywhere else:

(1) the computer plays multiple defense lines before admitting success

(2) the system allows alternative solutions to be played out to success rather than prompt the irritated user to find a better solution

(3) the system allows the user to play wrong lines and keeps replying with moves and not just with words like "wrong, try again".

(I am the chess programmer, author of this chess publishing platform.)

[Mate in 1 interactive exercises](https://szachydzieciom.pl/?page_id=63160)

[Mate in 2 interactive exercises](https://szachydzieciom.pl/?page_id=63164)